# Stopping tabs from changing

Tags: android, tabs

What I need unless my tablet is connected to a server I cant have the tabs being changed. I have a tab host that is all run off of the same java file. I figure all I need to do is have some sort of a test in the file to say unless boolean is true dont let the code change the tab. However I dont know how to do this? If you need to see any of my code just leave that in the comment box. Thanks for all your help !

Comment: I don't understand your question, are you asking how to know if you're app is connected to your server or not?

Comment: My question is. is there a way to make it so when you click on a tab. It will not work unless I have set something so it will become active again. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess you can try disabling/enabling clicks on the tabs by calling:

```
myTabHost.getTabWidget().setClickable(isConnectedToServer);
```

But I'm not sure that's good UX, how about letting your users change tabs, but if the content can't be reached displaying a message inside the main view of the tab "server unreachable, check your internet connection" or something like that.

UPDATE:
Try this instead (for each of your tabs):

```
myTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setEnabled(false);
myTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(false);
myTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(false);
```

ANOTHER UPDATE:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private TabWidget mTabWidget = null;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mTabWidget = myTabHost.getTabWidget();
    ...
}

protected void refreshTabs(boolean isConnected) {
    mTabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(0).setEnabled(isConnected);
    mTabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(isConnected);
    mTabWidget.getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(isConnected);
}
```

Now you can call `refreshTabs` whenever you want in your code to make them enabled/disabled.

Comment: so what I did was `th.getTabWidget().setClickable(connected);` and the th is defined by `final TabHost th = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);` however it doesnt work, when its not connected it will still change the tab, what did I do wrong?

Comment: It works thanks! however I have it in the onCreate section so when I change the boolean to true it wont change to true because its not realizing it, but if I move it out of on create it wont recognize the TabHost. Where should I put this in order for it to work?

Comment: you can create a new field called mTabWidget, and assign it in your onCreate: mTabWidget = myTagHost.getTabWidget(); and then later you can always refer to your tab widget by accessing that field: mTabWidget.getChild...

Comment: could you update your answer and show me how to do that by anychance because I dont understand on how to do that.